# Implement dry-run mode in python using mocks

Tags: python, mocking

Let's say you have a Python module which at some point makes calls to methods which have side effects like writing to a file. Say you want to have a dry-run mode where it only pretends to do what it is supposed to do but doesn't actually do it. How should one go about implementing this dry-run aspect which presents itself across different methods.
e.g.

```
import os.path

class Foo

  def ReadSomething(self):
    with open('/some/path', 'r') as f:
      print f.read()

  def WriteSomething(self, content):
    if not os.path.isfile('/some/path'):
      with open('/some/path', 'w') as f:
        f.write(content)
```

So I thought of using `unittest.mock` library to patch all the external APIs on the fly based on a variable like dry_run.
That is something along the lines of:

```
@DryRunPatcher('open')
@DryRunPatcher(os.path, 'isfile', return_value=True)
def WriteSomething(self, content, mock_isfile, mock_open):
```

Then DryRunPatcher would be something like:

```
def DryRunPatcher(*patch_args, **patch_kwargs):
  def Decorator(func):
    def PatchIfDrunRun(*args, **kwargs):
      self_arg = args[0]  # assuming it's a method
      if self_arg._dry_run_mode:
        with mock.patch.object(*patch_args, **patch_kwargs):
          return func(*args, **kwargs)
      else:
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return PatchIfDryRun
  return Decorator
```

The code above might not work but you get the idea. However the issue is I guess mock is expected to be used for unit testing only. What else can one use to patch out external APIs to implement a dry-run mode? I prefer the method itself be agnostic of the dry-run mode and not have to wrap every call with a side effect itself.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I encounter similar necessity: I got REST API client for some service, which had some CRUD operation. And I wish my script could be executed in dry-run mode, so user could check logs and get overall idea what would happen if he will execute program with some parameters. More over, some methods are not harmful and should be executed (recursive reads of some objects), but some should be avoided.
  Reading your proposal about mock methods lead me to (as I think) very nice solution: you can create a proxy class, where you can decide which methods should be executed and which should be 'mocked'. And by mocking you can decide what you would like to do: just print a message skip or do similar actions in the safe place (temp directory).
  Here how it could look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, some_parameter):
        self._some_parameter = some_parameter

    def read_something(self):
        print 'Method `read_something` from class Foo: {}'.format(self._some_parameter)

    def write_something(self, content):
        print 'Method `write_something` from class Foo: {} {}'.format(self._some_parameter, content)


class FooDryRunProxy(Foo):
    def __init__(self, some_parameter, dry_run=False):
        super(FooDryRunProxy, self).__init__(some_parameter=some_parameter)
        self._dry_run = dry_run

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        attr = object.__getattribute__(self, name)
        is_dry = object.__getattribute__(self, '_dry_run')
        if is_dry and hasattr(attr, '__call__') and name.startswith('write_'):
            def dry_run_method(*args, **kwargs):
                func_args = list()
                if args:
                    func_args.extend(str(a) for a in args)
                if kwargs:
                    func_args.extend('%s=%s' % (k, v) for k, v in kwargs.items())

                print("[DRY-RUN] {name}({func_args})".format(name=name, func_args=', '.join(func_args)))

            return dry_run_method
        else:
            return attr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo_normal = FooDryRunProxy(some_parameter='bar')
    foo_normal.read_something()
    foo_normal.write_something('got-something-?')

    foo_dry_run = FooDryRunProxy(some_parameter='bar', dry_run=True)
    foo_dry_run.read_something()
    foo_dry_run.write_something('got-something-?')
```

Here is output from it:

```
Method `read_something` from class Foo: bar
Method `write_something` from class Foo: bar got-something-?

Method `read_something` from class Foo: bar
[DRY-RUN] write_something(got-something-?)
```

Of course it's not 100% reliable solution, especially if the code you are going to wrap is 3rd party and could change somehow. But at least it could help you if you got huge class and you don't want to override all the methods.
Hope it would help someone.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you are looking for, but let's give this a try:

***CODE:***

```
def fake(state=False):
    def wrapper(function):
        def fakefunc(self, *args, **kwargs):
            print("I'm doing nothing!")
        if state:
            return fakefunc
        return function
    return wrapper


class Foo:

    @fake(True)
    def write_something(self, content):
        if not os.path.isfile('/some/path'):
            with open('/some/path', 'w') as f:
                f.write(content)
```

---

***DEMO:***

```
foo = Foo()
foo.write_something('hello fake!')
```

---

***OUTPUT:***

```
I'm doing nothing!
```

Comment: You are switching between the fake function and the real function. Also whether the fake or real function is picked is decided at module load time.

Comment: Ideally I want the body of the real function to have no idea that there is a dry-run mode. However since the real function might do some network, file system, etc. operation I'd rather only mock those (say expensive or with side effect) operations. So I don't have to write two functions: real and fake or wrap every file system operation with an "if dryrun:" check.
Lastly, the dryrun mode is determined at run time, say, with a command line flag.

Comment: Still not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I do know, that if you want to do something like this during runtime (which is almost what python only has, since it is not a compiled language), and you want to make the behaviour to depend on a flag, you have to write `if flag:` at some point..

Comment: The code I put in the question sort of does what I want to achieve but it uses the Python unittest.mock library which I guess is not intended to be used for non-test code. So I was wondering how can I do the same with a library or some technique that doesn't need unittest.mock.
Also on the run-time flag, you're right you need some variable to decide the behavior. In that code self._dry_run_mode would be that variable. The decorator was turning the WriteSomething method into a method which reads that variable and decides whether or not to mock out file I/O APIs.